# get Equation result - Python

Tags: python, numpy, equation, coefficients

I have a vector contains the coefficients of some equation by this code

```
numenator = np.poly(numenatorRoots)
```

now I want to substitute specific number in this equation to get the numerical result according to this number, my question is : How can I do that ? is there a function would help me with this?

Comment: Check out [numpy.polyval](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html).

Comment: Can you give a sample equation? I think i can offer alternative solution!

Comment: Actualy it's transfer function generated from given zeros and poles provided by users @Emmanuel